# Salvar imagem em Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como salvar a imagem vinda do `BD` em uma pasta qualquer existente no projeto ?
Preciso criar uma pasta nova ou salvar a imagem em uma pasta qualquer dentro do app para poder usá-la em uma `View`.

Meu código:

```
byte[] imageBytes;
var FileImage = new Image();
imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Foto); \\ Foto já está preenchida, é do tipo string
FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

Comment: Ok, e qual a dificuldade que você está encontrando? Em salvar a imagem, em criar um novo diretório ?

Comment: @JcSaint Não sei como fazer isso, nunca fiz. Poderia me dar uma ajuda ?

Comment: Só consegui fazer até ai @JcSaint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para salvar a imagem você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

1. Crie um [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) passando o seu `Array` no construtor;
2. Carregue a imagem para o `stream` usando [Imafe.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx)
3. Use [suaImagem.Save("nomeImagem", ImageFormat.Jpeg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx)

   `var arrayImagem = ObtenhaArrayImagem();
   using (var img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(arrayImagem)){img.Save("nomaImagem.jpg", mageFormat.Jpeg);}`

Referências:

[SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102005/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-file)

[Documentação Xamarin System.Drawing.Imaging](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Drawing.Imaging/)

[Adicionar Referências Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: aqui fala que o "Image" não contem a definição "FromStream"

Comment: você tem a referência do `System.Drawing.Imaging` ?

Comment: Não, vou adicionar aqui.

Comment: Não achei no nuget não.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Drawing.Imaging/

Comment: ainda não achei como adicionar no projeto. kkk

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: beleza, eu tentei aqui mas deu erro "the activex type library was exported from a .net assembly and cannot be added"

Comment: tem outra forma de fazer isso ?